# Change Cell Background When Clicked

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm setting up a system that tracks submissions from my employees in Google Sheets. Each day I check to see if they have submitted the proper paperwork. What I am wanting to accomplish is, when I click (or select) a cell with that employee's name, I want to change the background color when I click (or select) that cell.

Nothing I've tried has worked.

```
var color = [ 
   ["#06c646"] 
  ];

var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell();
cell.setBackground(color);
```

Nothing seems to be doing what I want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with jQuery:

```
$(selector).on("click", function() { // add cell's class/id here
    $(this).css({'background-color':'blue'});
});
```